# How to shallow copy char* to std::string?

Tags: c++, string

I wonder if it's possible to shallow copy `char*` to `std::string`.

Comment: you can just assign the [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) to the `char *` but what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I don't see why this question has been downvoted.  The answer is "no", but it's a reasonable question (QByteArray from Qt *does* have this capability for example).

Comment: @EdChum I'm trying to copy `char*` to `std::string` not the reversed way.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood I thought you wanted to just assign a pointer to the underlying char array from a `string` to a `char*`. It'd be useful to fully flesh out your question

Comment: @ZackLee If you want to copy rather than steal ownership, I'm not sure I'd call that "shallow copy". It's not too clear what you mean as "shallow" versus "deep" copy tends to refer to situations in which you have a choice to make, but a character buffer is a character buffer and has no indirection inside it. If it's the _pointer_ you want to copy then it's a case of ownership transferral as covered by lubgr's answer. I propose altering your question with better terminology to fully explain what it is that you want to do, and why: a single sentence doesn't cut it.

Comment: @EdChum `string::data()` returns `const char*`, so it may need to `const_cast`. Then it can do string operations defined in ``<cstring> but have to be aware of length and other stuff. The topic is similar to "use vector/array as char*"

Comment: @HanXIAO that's true but the question was a little vague on initial reading

Comment: @EdChum yeah, I am just offering some little add-ups.

Comment: @HanXIAO "*`string::data()` returns `const char*`*" - in C++17 there is an overload of `data()` that returns a non-const `char*`.  In earlier versions, you can use `operator[]` with index 0 instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you aim at constructing a `std::string` object with a `char*` without copying the data: no, this is impossible. `std::string` owns its resources, it can't refer to another `char*`. This is also why the appropriate constructor takes a `const char*`, not a `char*`: it doesn't modify the data, but copies it.

In C++17, you have `std::string_view` which is exactly meant for referring to a string (literal) that it doesn't own. Note that this view isn't intended to modify the data, its hence constructed with `const char*` again, not `char*`.

Comment: I'd forgetten about `std::string_view` - excellent suggestion.

Comment: @user463035818 That was indeed nebulous. Hope the answer is clearer now.

Comment: yes better, actually on a second thought I understood what you meant, but it wasnt that clear. Anyhow you got my upvote already

Answer (score 3):

All the `std` containers (and `std::string` is basically a container of `char`s) do own their data and have value semantics. Thus, no you cannot shallow copy a `char*` to a `std::string` out-of-the-box. 
There are however different objects that can be used for this purpose, to make the difference obvious they are called `..._view`, eg since C++17 there is `std::string_view`.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it should be possible to implement `string` constructor or member function taking a pointer to buffer (and size / capacity) with ownership transfer (similar to `unique_ptr`). However it won't be very helpful since string buffers are supposed to be created by corresponding *allocator* so you'll end up with calling string allocator manually and / or with difficult to track bugs when pointer passed wasn't created by correct allocator. Also this would make small string optimization problematic.